# hive string json list to array with specific field

Tags: sql, arrays, json, hive, hiveql

I want to select array at string json list with specific field in hive.

For example,

```
[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"},{"key1":"val3","key2":"val4"},{"key1":"val5","key2":"val6"}]
```

return array of key1 value

```
[val1,val3,val5]
```

How can I make it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert string to JSON array: remove [], split by comma between } and {. Then extract val1 and collect_list to get an array of val1, see comments in the code:

```
with mytable as(--data example with single row
 select '[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"},{"key1":"val3","key2":"val4"},{"key1":"val5","key2":"val6"}]' as json_string 
)

select collect_list(                             --collect array
                    get_json_object(json_map_string,'$.key1') --key1 extracted
                   ) as key1_array   
from
(
select  split(regexp_replace(json_string,'^\\[|\\]$',''), --remove []
                          '(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)'                          --split by comma only after } and before {
                         ) as json_array                              --converted to array of json strings (map)
  from mytable
)s
 lateral view outer explode(json_array) e as json_map_string --explode array elements
;
```

Result:

```
key1_array
["val1","val3","val5"]
```